# Android firebase app is posting multiple values

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have simple app which gets the value(s) from a multiple choice listview. If I push the data the output in database, it is like:

- January
- January
- February
- February
- February
- March
- March
- etc...

It's repeating and I want just the checked items, e.g. January,
February, March, not repeated.

Here's my main activity.java

```
 FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        final DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();

        myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);
        getChoice = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, listContent);
        myList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        myList.setAdapter(adapter);
        getChoice.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String selected = "";
                int cntChoice = myList.getCount();
                SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray = myList.getCheckedItemPositions();
                for (int i = 0; i <=cntChoice;i++) {
                    if (sparseBooleanArray.get(i)) {
                        selected = myList.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                    }
                    myRef.push().setValue(selected);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You are calling your setValue method outside the `if`. You should set the value inside the if so it writes only once. Change your code to this:

```
            for (int i = 0; i <=cntChoice;i++) {
                if (sparseBooleanArray.get(i)) {
                    selected = myList.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                    myRef.push().setValue(selected);
                }
            }
```